# Inequality for extremal values of product of Hermitian matrices

Tags: inequalities, matrix-theory

I am looking for a reference to verify the following inequality, where $X$ and $Y$ are Hermitian positive semidefinite matrices:
$$
\lambda_n(X^{1/2}YX^{1/2}) = \lambda_n(XY) \leq \lambda_n(X)\lambda_1(Y).
$$
This might be too trivial for MathOverflow but I am completely blanking on this.

Comment: Why does $XY$ have real eigenvalues?

Comment: @Alf: $X=AA^*$, $Y=BB^*$, and $XY=A(A^*BB^*)$ has the same eigenvalues as $(A^*BB^*)A=(A^*B)(A^*B)^*\succeq0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892626/singular-values-of-product-of-matrices

Answer (score 1):

Just combining my comments to form an explicit answer. Write $X=AA^*$ and $Y=BB^*$. Then $XY$ has the same eigenvalues as $(A^*B)(A^*B)^*$, and so

$$\lambda_n(XY)=\sigma_n(A^*B)^2\leq\big(\sigma_n(A^*)\sigma_1(B)\big)^2=\lambda_n(X)\lambda_1(Y),$$

where the inequality follows from [[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892626/singular-values-of-product-of-matrices]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892626/singular-values-of-product-of-matrices).